# PHPStorm Encodes Query only sometimes

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, ide, phpstorm

So i got this query in my File if i run the code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.V_Admin_Hülse ORDER BY Kaliber DESC"; 
$sql = $conn->query($query);
```

this is $conn it is in a diffrent file but required:

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database = $database;", $uid, $pwd);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8);
```

if i run the file in debug and look into $query it reads:

```
$query = SELECT * FROM dbo.V_Admin_HÃ¼lse ORDER BY Kaliber DESC
```

And there is no problem running it.
In a different file i got another Statment with an umlaut

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.T_Geschossform ORDER BY Abkürzung ASC";
$sql = $conn->query($query);
```

but when i run that in Debug i get

```
 $query = SELECT * FROM dbo.T_Geschossform ORDER BY Abkürzung ASC
```

and quits with an exception!

Why is that?
And how do i get it to do it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i added

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

and after i closed and reopend the Projekt it read

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.T_Geschossform ORDER BY Abk�rzung ASC"
```

i replaced the � with an ü and now it works fine....

Strange things are happening... 
Can anyone explain?

Comment: What file encoding did you had there in first place? Replicate your old code (which you can still get via Local History functionality) in new file and check there.

Comment: None only had:
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: I was talking about that file with SQL code -- the `meta` tag in your comment suggests that it is a HTML file...

Comment: Its a .php file with mixed HTML and PHP the SQL is in the php script.

Comment: OK .. so what file encoding did you had before for that file (`Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Encoding`) and what do you have now? So far it sounds like that file (at least those changes) was saved in wrong encoding. if it happens again - please verify that file encoding is detected correctly (it shown in status bar, for example).

Comment: It set to use UTF-8 as default for all files.
And i got a similar file where it work that is what confuses me.

Comment: There was some change in IDE when upgrading from v8 to v9 -- file encoding which originally (v8) where treated as UTF-8 (at least in my case) were all detected as System Default in v9 (Windows-1252 in my case) so I had to go trough aforementioned `File Encoding` dialog and change Default Project Encoding to be UTF-8 (which got applied only after IDE restart) otherwise IDE was treating my files in incorrect encoding. *Possibly* that is what happened to you as well

Comment: I had IDE Encoding set to UTF-8 but not Project Encoding! 
Is now Set after Restart it works fine... only thing is why it worked on the other Files but not on this one...